# Spread operator completely clearing state in my reducer when I switch inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

all I am fairly new to React, and Redux and have been stuck with this issue for an entire day now. The data is dispatching from my component to my action creator, then to my reducer, and the state is being updated. However, when I change inputs and begin typing, it clears all other data in the form except for the data of the input I am currently typing in. If I take out the spread operator, the data then stays, but from every tutorial, I have seen this should not happen. Am I doing something wrong?

AddProject.js (form component)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./AddProjects.module.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  validateProjectId,
  validateProjectDescription,
  validateProjectName,
  projectStartDate,
  projectEndDate,
  submitHandler
} from "../../Redux/createProject/action";

const AddProject = props => {
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log("aaa", props);
  // }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.addProjectContainer}>
      <h5>Create / Edit Project form</h5>
      <hr />
      <form>
        <div>
          <input
            defaultValue=""
            type="text"
            placeholder="Project Name"
            name="projectName"
            style={
              props.form.projectNameError
                ? { backgroundColor: "#F08080", opacity: "0.8" }
                : { backgroundColor: "white" }
            }
            onChange={e => props.validateProjectName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Unique Project ID"
            name="projectIdentifier"
            value={props.form.projectIdentifier}
            style={
              props.form.projectIdentifierError
                ? { backgroundColor: "#F08080", opacity: "0.8" }
                : { backgroundColor: "white" }
            }
            onChange={e => props.validateProjectId(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            placeholder="Project Description"
            name="description"
            value={props.form.description}
            style={
              props.form.descriptionError
                ? { backgroundColor: "#F08080", opacity: "0.8" }
                : { backgroundColor: "white" }
            }
            onChange={e => props.validateProjectDescription(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <h6>Start Date</h6>
        <div>
          <input
            type="date"
            name="start_date"
            value={props.form.start_date}
            onChange={e => props.projectStartDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <h6>Estimated End Date</h6>
        <div>
          <input
            type="date"
            name="end_date"
            value={props.form.end_date}
            onChange={e => props.projectEndDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="button" onClick={props.submitHandler}>
          <span>Submit</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
//state.form.projectName
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state.project);
  return {
    form: state.project
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    validateProjectName: payload => dispatch(validateProjectName(payload)),
    validateProjectId: payload => dispatch(validateProjectId(payload)),
    validateProjectDescription: payload =>
      dispatch(validateProjectDescription(payload)),
    projectStartDate: payload => dispatch(projectStartDate(payload)),
    projectEndDate: payload => dispatch(projectEndDate(payload)),
    submitHandler: () => dispatch(submitHandler())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProject);
```

action.js (action creator)

```
import {
  PROJECT_NAME_CHANGE,
  PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE,
  PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE,
  START_DATE_CHANGE,
  END_DATE_CHANGE,
  SUBMIT_HANDLER,
  PROJECT_NAME_ERROR,
  PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR,
  PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR
} from "./constants";

export const projectNameChange = projectName => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_NAME_CHANGE,
    projectName
  };
};

export const projectNameError = () => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_NAME_ERROR
  };
};

export const projectIdChange = projectIdentifier => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE,
    projectIdentifier
  };
};

export const projectIdError = () => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR
  };
};

export const projectDescriptionChange = description => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE,
    description
  };
};

export const projectDescriptionError = () => {
  return {
    type: PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR
  };
};

export const projectStartDate = start_date => {
  return {
    type: START_DATE_CHANGE,
    start_date
  };
};

export const projectEndDate = end_date => {
  return {
    type: END_DATE_CHANGE,
    end_date
  };
};

export const submitHandler = () => {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT_HANDLER
  };
};

export function validateProjectName(payload) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (payload.length <= 30) {
      dispatch(projectNameChange(payload));
    } else {
      dispatch(projectNameError());
    }
  };
}

export function validateProjectId(payload) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (payload.length < 6) {
      dispatch(projectIdChange(payload));
    } else {
      dispatch(projectIdError());
    }
  };
}

export function validateProjectDescription(payload) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (payload.length < 256) {
      dispatch(projectDescriptionChange(payload));
    } else {
      dispatch(projectDescriptionError());
    }
  };
}

// thunk call passed project name
// validateProjectName(name){
//     if(name.length>4 && ){
//         dispatchEvent(setName)
//     }
//     else{
//         dispatch(setNameError)
//     }
// }
```

index.js (Reducer)

```
  PROJECT_NAME_CHANGE,
  PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE,
  PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE,
  START_DATE_CHANGE,
  END_DATE_CHANGE,
  SUBMIT_HANDLER,
  PROJECT_NAME_ERROR,
  PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR,
  PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR
} from "./constants";

const initialState = {
  projectName: "",
  projectIdentifier: "",
  description: "",
  start_date: "",
  end_date: "",
  projectNameError: false,
  projectIdentifierError: false,
  descriptionError: false
};

const createProjectReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PROJECT_NAME_CHANGE:
      //   console.log("We changed project name!", state.projectName, action);
      return {
        ...state,
        projectName: action.projectName
      };
    case PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE:
      //   console.log("We changed project id!", state, action.projectIdentifier);
      return {
        ...state,
        projectIdentifier: action.projectIdentifier,
        projectIdentifierError: false
      };
    case PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE:
      //   console.log("We changed project description", state, action.description);
      return { ...state, description: action.description };
    case START_DATE_CHANGE:
      //   console.log("We changed the start date", state, action.payload);
      return { ...state, start_date: action.payload };
    case END_DATE_CHANGE:
      //   console.log("We changed the end date", state, action.payload);
      return { ...state, end_date: action.payload };
    case PROJECT_NAME_ERROR:
      //   console.log("There was an error with the project name!", state);
      return { ...state, projectNameError: true };
    case PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR:
      //   console.log("There was an error with the project Id!", state);
      return { projectIdentifierError: true };
    case PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR:
      //   console.log("There was an error with the project description!", state);
      return { ...state, descriptionError: true };
    case SUBMIT_HANDLER:
      console.log("We submitted yayy", state);
      return initialState;
    //const formData = state;
    //console.log(formData);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default createProjectReducer;
```

constants.js

```
export const PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE = "PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_CHANGE";
export const PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE = "PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_CHANGE";
export const START_DATE_CHANGE = "START_DATE_CHANGE";
export const END_DATE_CHANGE = "END_DATE_CHANGE";
export const SUBMIT_HANDLER = "SUBMIT_HANDLER";
export const PROJECT_NAME_ERROR = "PROJECT_NAME_ERROR";
export const PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR = "PROJECT_IDENTIFIER_ERROR";
export const PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR = "PROJECT_DESCRIPTION_ERROR";
```

rootReducer.js

```
const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  return {
    project: createProjectReducer(state.createProject, action)
  };
};

export default rootReducer;
```

index.js (store creator)

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import rootReducer from "./Redux/rootReducer";

const composeEnhancers =
  (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: I don't see the spread operator used at all in the code you posted.

Comment: I accidentally copied my action creator twice they are in my reducer

Answer (score 0):

Using redux to manage the state of a component is very bad practice. What you should do instead is to use `useState` to save the state of each of your inputs and control them with the `onChange`
Redux should be used ONLY for variables which are UI related and which have to be transported between multiple components all around the website.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html for more information

You need to know that everytime you update your redux store, the store is first copied (fully) then the new values are added and then the current store is replaced by the new one. Which drives to a lot of performance issues and memory leak.

Comment: So would it be better to use useState as a local state for the form and then once it is done I can send it up to Redux?

Comment: If you need these data outside the component, then yes!

Answer (score 0):

In redux reducer you should always return the entire new version of the state, not just the updated parameter

exemple

```
return Object.assign({},prevState,{field: action.value});
```

(We don't see your reducer in your post but I guess that this is the problem)

Good documentation here - https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers/

Comment: A better practice is to use the spread operator but chanding the value only :
return { ...prevState, field: action.value }

Comment: My reducer is my index.js file but where would be the best place to initialize the prevState? In the reducer? I am confused about using the spread operator because from what I understand if you do return { ....state, projectName: blah} then only project name should be changed and the rest of the state should remain as the previous state?

Comment: Fixed my reducer to actually show my reducer did not realize I copied the action creator twice! My bad!

Comment: I quite don't agree with Psyycker, it's not a good idea to mix redux and useState. If the data is used at multiple places, it's better to handle it in redux only... my opinion...

Comment: Your code looks ok, could you share the store creation and the component with the provider,  Maybe you are re-initialising something there...

Comment: I added my store creator and root reducer which I believe should be everything redux related. I am also using thunk for middleware

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your store creation

```
project: createProjectReducer(state.createProject, action)
```

should be

```
project: createProjectReducer(state.project, action)
```

The state is lost by not being passed to the sub reducer

Comment: Created a new post as my first answer was not resolving your problem

Comment: The root reducer is responsible to dispatch the substates & actions between the subreducers,  You declared this part of the state with the 'project' key but pass the 'state.createProject' to the reducer, state.createProject was always null and therefore taking the default state of that subreducer

Comment: Okay, I understand now thank you so much for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to vote/select as best answer :-)